# is entry.key.id unique across all entries of a model?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a model. When I list id of all entries of the model. Some id of them are same. When I create the entries, didn't defined id for them it's assigned automatically. Maybe some of them have a different parents.

So is entry.key.id unique for across all entries of a model? or it's defend on parent of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it depends on the parent. The *path* - that is, parent kind, parent ID, child kind, child ID - is unique, but child ID is reused (although not deterministically) across different entity groups.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: Google App Engine Datastore Documentation

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities.html#Kinds_IDs_and_Names

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/